# Writing an API for checked subtraction

Tags: java, integer, guava

I have to write an API for checked subtraction where the input minuend can be < 0 but subtrahend can't be < 0. I think I've covered all the cases of underflow and overflow. With given conditions the range of subtrahend is `[Long.MIN_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE]` and of minuend is `[0, Long.MAX_VALUE]`; with these limits overflow is not possible and underflow can happen if subtrahend > minuend and in that case setting `Long.MIN_VALUE` as the minimum possible difference seems legit.

```
public static long checkedSubtract(final long minuend, final long subtrahend) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(subtrahend >= 0, "Subtrahend must be >= 0");

    long difference;
    try {
        difference = LongMath.checkedSubtract(minuend, subtrahend);
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        // With the precondition of subtrahend >= 0, this operation can not
        // overflow and if it underflows, return minimum possible difference 
        difference = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    return difference;
}
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could affirm my logic and/or point out any mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorporating exceptions to handle expected situations is never a good idea. Creating an exception instance in Java is significantly slower than the `if` condition that would prevent the exception. Exceptions should be exceptions.

Additionally, as maaartinus says, you should not ned to declare the `difference` outside the try block. Even if you accept the exception as valid, your code would be simpler as:

```
try {
    return LongMath.checkedSubtract(minuend, subtrahend);
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    // With the precondition of subtrahend >= 0, this operation can not
    // overflow and if it underflows, return minimum possible difference 
    return Long.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

Regardless, you give no indication where the `LongMath` class comes from. Still, your situation would be much simpler as:

```
public static long checkedSubtract(final long  minuend, final long subtrahend) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(subtrahend >= 0, "Subtrahend must be >= 0");
    long result = minuend - subtrahend;
    // if the result underflows, it will be larger than the start balance
    return result > minuend ? Long.MIN_VALUE : result;
}
```

Comment: Actually, is this wrong? Overflow happens, if minuend < Long.MIN_VALUE + subtrahend. But I guess, what you are doing is better, because difference is computed only once.

Answer (score 4):

I guess your logic is fine. I just don't like what you do with the variable `difference`. You could return directly instead and save the variable and two lines.

In case the overflow s probable, you're wasting a lot of time because of the exception. You could do something like

```
long result = minuend - subtrahend;
return minuend >= 0 | (minuend ^ result) >= 0 ? result : Long.MIN_VALUE;
```

instead (condition adapted from `LongMath.checkedSubtract`). You could test it both against your original implementation (e.g. with a few random values) and against some known cases.

---

As suggested by user1071840, a simpler condition may be used:

```
return Long.MIN_VALUE + subtrahend > minuend ? minuend - subtrahend : Long.MIN_VALUE;
```

Actually, rolfl's condition is even simpler.

Comment: @user1071840 I don't see why your expression should be right. Maybe it is, can you show it?

Comment: Ouch, I forgot to replace the variable names.

Comment: if (Long.MIN_VALUE + subtrahend > minuend) {
            return Long.MIN_VALUE;

        } else {
            return minuend - subtrahend;
        }

Comment: Overflow will happen, if (minuend - subtrahend) < Long.MIN_VALUE, which means minuend < Long.MIN_VALUE + subtrahend. Unless, I've made a mistake in the signs with inequalities.

Comment: @user1071840 This makes sense. My more complicated condition is a direct simplification of `LongMath.checkedSubtract`.